# Who actually signs a Solana transaction?

Tags: transactions, payer, signer

The code below is copied from the code [here](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/hello-solana/native/tests/test.ts)

```
describe("hello-solana", () => {

    // Loading these from local files for development
    //
    const connection = new Connection(`http://localhost:8899`, 'confirmed');
    const payer = createKeypairFromFile(require('os').homedir() + '/.config/solana/id.json');
    const program = createKeypairFromFile('./program/target/so/program-keypair.json');
  
    it("Say hello!", async () => {

        // We set up our instruction first.
        //
        let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
            keys: [
                {pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true}
            ],
            programId: program.publicKey,
            data: Buffer.alloc(0), // No data
        });

        // Now we send the transaction over RPC
        //
        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            connection, 
            new Transaction().add(ix), // Add our instruction (you can add more than one)
            [payer]
        );
    });
  })
```

In creating the `TransactionInstruction`, the following object was passed `{pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true}` setting the `payer.publicKey` as the signer.

Then later on, when submitting the transaction via `sendAndConfirmTransaction`, the `payer` is passed again as a signer:

```
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
 connection, 
 new Transaction().add(ix), // Add our instruction (you can add more than one)
 [payer]
)
```

Question is, why is the key that would be the signer specified twice? When constructing the transaction objects and when submitting the transaction?

Also checking the documentation of `sendAndConfirmTransaction` which can be seen [here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#sendAndConfirmTransaction) the type signature for the function is as follows:

```
sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection: Connection, transaction: Transaction, 
signers: Signer[], options?: ConfirmOptions): Promise<TransactionSignature>
```

I noticed that `signers` is an array. Meaning multiple signers can be passed in right? If so, what does it mean to have multiple signers passed in? Is that how multi-signature features are implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the instruction is being built, where the `keys` specify the accounts that the instruction requires.
In this case there is only 1 account (`payer.publicKey`) and it is required to be a signer. The actual signing does not occur here, it is simply specifying that the account must be a signer.

```
let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
            keys: [
                {pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true}
            ],
            programId: program.publicKey,
            data: Buffer.alloc(0), // No data
        });
```

Here the instruction above is being added to a new transaction and sent, with the `payer` specified as a signer to sign the transaction.

```
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
 connection, 
 new Transaction().add(ix), // Add our instruction (you can add more than one)
 [payer]
)
```

A common example of where multiple signers are passed in is when initializing an account using a new randomly generated keypair.

Check out the `create-account` program example:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/create-account/native/tests/test.ts#L38

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/create-account/native/program/src/lib.rs#L17

Comment: Why can't I omit `[payer]` since `isSigner:true` is already set when creating `TransactionInstruction`?

Comment: I looked at the `create-account` and I ask, why should `newKeypair` be included as part of the signer (and not just have `payer`)? I ask, since `newKeypair` is not created yet and hence does not contain any SOL, how then can it be able to sign and pay a transaction?

Comment: `isSigner:true` is saying that the `payer.publicKey` must be a signer (but the actual signing does not occur here). Think of it as creating a form that requires someone's signature. 

Including `[payer]` as a signer in `sendAndConfirmTransaction` is when `payer` actually signs. Think of this as the user required as a signer on the form actually signing the form and then sending it out.

Comment: When initializing a new account with a new keypair, the keypair has to be included as a signer on the instruction basically to prove that the whoever controls that keypair approves using that keypair to initialize a new account.